# L20n.js framework doesn't render text inside Angular views

Tags: angularjs, partials, l20n

I am using l20n.js to provide localization for an Angular app. It works for elements inside index.html, but the localized text is not displayed inside of an Angular partial view. Here is my project structure:

```
<!--app/index.html-->
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<link rel="localization" href="locales/manifest.json">
<script src="bower_components/l20n/l20n.js"></script>
</head>
<p data-l10n-id="about"></p>
<!--This is where partial.html gets rendered-->
<p ng-view=""></div>
</html>

<!--app/locales/en-US/strings.l20n-->
<pass "This text is rendered in the browser">
<fail "This text doesn't show up at all">

<!--app/views/partial.html-->
<p>This text is being displayed, so I know the partial view is being rendered.</p>
<p data-l10n-id="fail"></p>
```

My current working theory is that there is some kind of race condition; Angular is re-rendering something, l20n doesn't realize that a re-rendering took place and doesn't grab the translated text from the resource file. How can I fix this?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have a good answer to this at this point, but I'm interested in learning about use-cases and researching a proper solution.  You may want to check out Michał's [ng-l10n](https://github.com/EE/ng-l20n) as well as the [discussion about Angular](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mozilla.tools.l10n/Ku6KAtqJmX8) in the tools-l10n mailing list.

Comment: Also, I tried to run your example locally but I think I'm missing something.   Do I need the ngRoute module for the ng-view directive to work?

Comment: 2 years later, we are able to run l20n with angular 1.7 without any issue.  I might guess that l20n was improved to run with dynamic js frameworks since this question was asked.